# Best way to represent language tokens for an autocompletion scenario

Tags: language-agnostic, autocomplete, token

As some of you know, I'm developing my own IDE. You might think "oh no, another one?!" - don't worry, no one's forcing you to use it, and I doubt it will be seriously published anyway.

So, onwards to the main issue. I'm trying to implement an autocompletion system. The exact UI is not the concern. **However, storing language/library tokens in a flexible way, is my main problem.**

Let's say we're suggesting CSS selectors OR attributes to the user. We'd have something like:

```
- css/core
  - a                      // anchor tag
  - etc                    // all valid html tags
  - .stuff                 // class name parsed from user project
  - ?etc                   // more stuff parsed from user project (ids, classes...)
- css/properties
  - border                 // regular css properties - we also need to associate
                           // <border-style> and <color> value tokens
  - etc                    // the rest of them
- css/values/border-style  // property value tokens
  - solid
  - dotted
- css/values/color
  - red
  - green
  - fucshia
```

So each token gets a namespace so we can track between tokens. Similarly to BNF, some token values are made up of subtokens such as the case for border and color.

**1.** Don't forget that we need to store anything that might relate to languages with exotic syntax. **2.** Also, it is important to note that I will need to somehow merge the above information with context-dependent one, such as a list of class names gathered from the project's files. This should be fast and efficient, without causing any duplicate tokens etc.

So, to conclude, the thing here is very complicated, and I can't honestly think of a way to get a general and flexible solution. Keep in mind the IDE should cater for any kind of language, making this even more complicated.

I'm not sure if this question is better suited in, for example, [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), so I'll leave it up to mods to decide.

Comment: I don't think you *can* do it the way you want. Sure, in a regular language such as CSS, possibly. But in a context sensitive grammar, the same token may have multiple meanings depending on context. So to namespace it out by token isn't really going to work well (me thinks)...

Comment: @ircmaxell A very valid point! Too bad it only puts me one step back. :D

Comment: What you're defining here is just the possible feeds of data that can be used, but what's important is the context dependent slots you're going to push them in. And, of course, this changes per document type; worse, imagine PHP with HTML, CSS and JavaScript in one document :) the joys ...

Comment: You need to determine the context in which a token is typed in. Is it inside of a {} block? Does it start with a @, if not, it's probably a selector. Does it start with a #? if so, it's probably an ID, so you can suggest matching IDs from the adjacent HTML document. Is it inside the {} tags following a selector? Then it's probably a rule. Does it come after the :? It's a value. Of course I'm simplifying, but that's the gist of how it's done.

Comment: @Truth I'm leaving that part to the code parser. My problem is getting to *store* the tokens in the first place.

Comment: wrt not having duplicates: the faster solution is, imho, create an independent list in which you put *all* the possible autocomplete values, pay `O(n log n)` to sort it, and then find duplicates in `O(n)`

Comment: @Christian, So you are saying that you dont know how(or what would be the best way) to create dictionary of keywords?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked on an IDE called [SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/martinkonicek/archive/2010/08/01/resharper-for-sharpdevelop-new-features.aspx). Let me start with a more general discussion before I get to the storage question.

I don't think you can solve autocompletion properly in a generic way. Most IDEs support various languages by having a *plugin* for each of the languages and it is entirely up to the plugin to figure out what a completion list should look like based on the current position of the cursor in the document.

The IDE only provides a simple interface that the plugins implement. For example, the code in the IDE showing autocompletion could look like this:

```
getAutocompletionList(editor) {
  plugin = editor.languagePlugin;
  plugin.getAutocompletionList(editor.cursorPosition, editor.parsedDocument);
}
```

A `CSSLanguagePlugin` and `PHPLanguagePlugin` would then have completely separate implementations of `getAutocompletionList` - one would be used when editing CSS, the other when editing PHP.

As others pointed out, the context around the cursor is important. For example, when editing the following CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-align: <cursor>
```

The contexts would be:

```
[cssTopLevelContext] {
    [cssPropertyContext]: [cssPropertyValueContext]
}
```

The implementation of the CSS plugin would then do the following:

```
// CSSLanguageBinding
getAutocompletionList(cursorPosition, document) {
    completionContext = this.getCompletionContext(cursorPosition, document);
    // completionContext is { 
    //     'name': 'cssPropertyValueContext', 
    //     'propertyName': 'text-align' 
    // }
    return this.completionDatabase.getCompletionList(completionContext);
    // returns ['left', 'center', 'right'];
}
```

Now we get to your question - the *completion database*. Again, it could (and probably should) be a different implementation for different language plugins - in PHP you work with classes, methods and variables, and have to care about visibility (private, public, protected). In CSS you work with tags, classes and properties.

As you correctly pointed out, the completion database should consist of:

- common tokens
- tokens imported by the current project
- tokens in the current project itself

In SharpDevelop, the 'common tokens' part is not there, as any project imports the standard library, so it enough to analyze all the imported libraries when opening a project.

In PHP you could do the same and you could cache the token database for already seen libraries.

Now we get to the storage format. To offer autocompletion in PHP, you will need to know the current class, its base class and interface hierarchy, methods in all the base classes and interfaces and their visibility, variables visible in current context and their types (not always possible in PHP) and so on.

For this reason, I think a relational database is not a good choice. How will you store all the classes, interfaces and methods there and navigate the inheritance hierarchy? SharpDevelop stores all this in memory as object model (Class has a base type, list of interfaces, list of members etc.). 8000 items is not a very large number, and if you stored 8000 items in a relational database, it would be so small that the database engine would keep it all in RAM anyway.

SharpDevelop keeps all the completion information in memory and when you open a 700K line project in SharpDevelop, the memory consumption is still pretty low. I suggest you initialize your autocompletion data structures upon opening of a project and keep them in memory. As others said, you have to update them in the background as user is typing (introducing new methods, renaming fields, etc.).

So that's it for PHP. For CSS, a data structure similar to what you outlined in your question seems very reasonable. You could load this into memory from a structured file upon the start of the IDE / opening a project / opening the first CSS file.

---

As an end note, implementing good autocompletion for CSS shouldn't be that hard. For PHP, it will be much more difficult and you could start with something simple - offering the 8000 tokens from the standard library plus offering *words that the user typed* somewhere else in the project. Such approach is used by editors like Sublime Text and works surprisingly well.

Comment: I've used your ide before. If I remember correctly, it was quite responsive, especially on the autocompletion part. Since I don't use flash much, I stopped using it, though. Regarding the answer in general, the terminology you've is very helpful, especially when I'm designing the system. Regarding the RDBM aspect, I wrote a small abstraction layer where completion items are stored in tables according to language - allowing me to have different schema per language.

Answer (score 3):

After some careful thought and advice from various people, a database is the only logical solution to store autocompletion information.

During this exercise, I wrote several scripts which parsed code/specifications to generate autocompletion code.

Here is where I realized that, for example, PHP has in excess of at least 8000 functions (=>autocompletion items).

As such, storing this information inside PHP files and loaded when the IDE is booted is just bad. Instead, I database will be storing this information.

Any project-specific automcompletion will be stored in separate DB tables, helping to avoid clogging main documentation table.

Comment: This is fine as far as it goes, but you'll want also to store complete type information and other complex attributes in a form where complex queries ("all defined names for int or int [] or class instances with int fields or types coercible to int or functions returning the above, listed in the order just mentioned") will work. SQL schema might be clumsy for this purpose. You might think of storing in a form ammenable to unification-based expert system-style rule satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

At my old job, we sold manufactured goods on our terrible website (I am an engineer, so I swear this terribleness was not my fault).  One day, the higher-ups decided they wanted a "recommended items" box on all of our products.

The common sense approach to this would be to build a really cool and interesting relationship between each product and all of the other products, and then provide the customer with relevant, current information about products that were actually related.  Unfortunately, nobody at my work knew how to get our pre-built website to do that.

Instead, they attached an array of five product IDs to each product.  These product IDs were hard-coded based on reccomendations by experienced salesman and common sense, and no fancy algorithms.

The moral of this story is that you might want to focus on the fact that the end-user of your IDE is only going to see about ten reccomendations, so maybe you should just think up a few rules that lead to a "pretty good" top ten list of potential variables: take some basic grammar rules and then predict based on things like proximity within the code, frequency of each variable, and that sort of thing.  Then you could put this thing to bed and focus on the more important parts of your IDE.

Comment: I don't think that's an accurate view of how people use code autocompleters in practice. When you're looking for a class or function, you browse the list of options; if it's not there, you need to be confident that that's because it doesn't exist, because you're going to go write it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the hard part is collecting the tokens to offer and matching them up to the right typing contexts. (Both typing as in which character of a partially-typed line to activate with what, and typing as in language type system.) Representing and querying the lists of options, by comparison, is easy and doesn't matter much; a naive approach is pretty much fine.

One thing that existing IDEs do it is they periodically take your code and compile it in a background thread, using a special version or mode of the compiler to produce a list of the functions/variables/etc that exist in the program. This list is alternately called either a "tags file", "browse information" or "program database". It stores the names, paths, types, and sometimes also some auto-extracted documentation for every function in the project; and for performance, it needs to work incrementally, that is, to avoid recompiling things that haven't changed, at least at the granularity of individual files. It also needs to be more tolerant of errors than a real compiler would be, because it operates on partially-typed code.

Then when you're typing, the compiler knows of some contexts in which the autocompleter should appear: after you type a '.' for functions, when you've typed part of a CSS attribute name, etc. These depend on pattern-matching partially typed code. There is no unifying principle to these; it's just a bunch of special cases, which vary from language to language. For example, when you type the space in "case SomeEnum.Foo:", some IDEs will find the enclosing switch statement, infer its type, find the definition of that enumeration type, and offer its values as options.

The practical consequence of all this is that you can't ever get a nice uniform representation of things your autocompleter can offer; instead, you have a mix of language-specific context-identification hacks, lists for the various contexts and more lists extracted by parsing. Many contexts will merge several lists together; eg, a CSS selector can have any HTML tag name, or an extract class name/ID, and the HTML tag names list is also used when typing HTML.